# Increase table item ID in PHP while loop and display other table items

Tags: php, html, css, mysql, azure-web-app-service

I have an azure PHP Web App with MySQL database.

I need to access 2 tables in the database and loop through each entry, displaying the content connected to each ID.

Database set up:

Driver

| driverID | driverName |
| --- | --- |
| (AI) 1 | Bob |

openJobs

| jobID | jobName | jobDate | destination | etc etc etc | driver_FK | driverName_FK |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| (AI) 1 | job 1 | Monday, 1st Sep | New Zealand | blah blah | (get from driver) | (get from Driver) |

Here is my code:
I also have a connection linked elsewhere. And I haven't added the join for the drivers name yet.

```
function openJobsList()
{
    $i = 4;

    global $conn;
    $query = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT openjobs.jobName, openjobs.jobType, openjobs.orderNumber, openjobs.referenceNumber, openjobs.pallets, openjobs.jobWeight, openjobs.jobStatus, driver.DriverID, driver.driverName
                                    FROM openjobs
                                    INNER JOIN driver ON openjobs.driver_fk = driver.DriverID                                    
                                    WHERE driver.DriverID = $i");

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {

        //$i++;

        $id = $row['DriverID'];
        //$driverName_fk = $row['driverName_fk'];
        $jobName = $row['jobName'];
        $jobType = $row['jobType'];
        $orderNumber = $row['orderNumber'];
        $referenceNumber = $row['referenceNumber'];
        $pallets = $row['pallets'];
        $jobWeight = $row['jobWeight'];
        $jobStatus = $row['jobStatus'];

        echo "<div class='card mainPageJobCard'>
                <div class='card-body'>
                    <div class='row justify-content-between'>
                        <div class='col-11'>
                            <h5 class='card-title'>Driver: {$id}</h5>
                        </div>
                        <div class='col-1'>
                            <a href='pages/webAddJob.php' class='btn btn-primary btn-sm text-light rounded-pill'>Add Job</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class='row'>
                        <div class='col pt-3'>
                            <table class='table table-bordered table-responsive'>
                                <thead>
                                 <tr class='table-light'>
                                        <th scope='col' class='col-2'>Job</th>
                                        <th scope='col'>Type</th>
                                        <th scope='col' class='col-2'>Order #</th>
                                        <th scope='col' class='col-2'>Reference</th>
                                        <th scope='col'>Pallets</th>
                                        <th scope='col'>Weight (kg)</th>
                                        <th scope='col' class='col-2'>Status</th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>

                                <tr>
                                    <th>{$jobName}</th>
                                    <td>{$jobType}</td>
                                    <td>{$orderNumber}</td>
                                    <td>{$referenceNumber}</td>
                                    <td>{$pallets}</td>
                                    <td>{$jobWeight}</td>
                                    <td>{$jobStatus}</td>
                                </tr>                                 
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>";
        //$i++;
        $id++;
    }


}
```

So far I can get the code to spit out the data entry with ID=4 (that's where they start and auto increment from there) but it only displays that 1 entry and none following it.

I'm really new to PHP, azure and MySQL so I'd also love to hear any other tips to clean up my code.

The function is being called in another php page with connection etc. And uses Bootstrap 5.

ISSUE PARTIALLY FIXED!

New issue:

Jobs attached to drivers are printing separately instead of all under the driver.

[Screenshot of what's running](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jGQh1.png)

Do I need another while loop to print jobs?

Comment: If you solved your orignal problem, post it as an answer to your own question and then create a new question with your new issue.  This helps keep questions concise and searchable.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, your issue is, that only jobs for the driver with the ID 4 are displayed. Your `while` loop looks good, so I suspect your MySQL query, where you are explicitly searching for jobs that have a driver, which is declared via the `join`, that has the ID 4, is the issue.

You said, you want to also have the entries following it, so I suggest to change the `where` clause, to find drivers with the ID of atleast 4, like this:

```
$query = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT openjobs.jobName, openjobs.jobType, openjobs.orderNumber, openjobs.referenceNumber, openjobs.pallets, openjobs.jobWeight, openjobs.jobStatus, driver.DriverID, driver.driverName
                                FROM openjobs
                                INNER JOIN driver ON openjobs.driver_fk = driver.DriverID                                    
                                WHERE driver.DriverID >= $i");
```

Alternativly you could just remove the check all together, to get all jobs, which are attached to a driver, and the corresponding driver:

```
$query = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT openjobs.jobName, openjobs.jobType, openjobs.orderNumber, openjobs.referenceNumber, openjobs.pallets, openjobs.jobWeight, openjobs.jobStatus, driver.DriverID, driver.driverName
                                FROM openjobs
                                INNER JOIN driver ON openjobs.driver_fk = driver.DriverID");
```

Comment: Thanks so much! Removing the 4 worked, I thought that the $i++ would increase it and I would then get 5 etc. Didn't even think to try it without.

Comment: Although now I am getting each table entry in a separate block, so the two jobs assigned to ID 6 have been displayed separately instead of both under driver 6. I will try and add a screenshot below. 

Any ideas on how to fix that and have them printing under one another? Do I need another while loop inside the main one that loops through the jobs?

Comment: Edited the original post to show screenshot :)

Comment: MySQL is running the query just once upon fetch and then iterates over the results, that is the reason, why the `$i++` did not help.
That's right, you will have to use a second loop. The outer (current) loop should find any driver with a job and add the block. The inner loop should find all jobs corresponding to that driver and print the table rows

Comment: Great thanks so much for your help. Any ideas on what I need to pass into the second while loop? while( ?? ) { } etc..